# smart code generation macros

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode

How could we create macros for smart code generation. For example in intellij, if i write a type that does not exist, intellij would be able to automatically generate an entire class of that type. I would proceed to add a couple of attributes, and then again by smart code generation, intellij would create constructors, getters and setters for my class. What extensions or packages can we use for this? Or how how could we implement this?

An example with Java:

Lets say i fast want to create a new class in java, so i would press alt+insert -> "Animal" -> Enter and i get something like this:
`public class Animal {..}`
 This is not really hard or annoying to write myself, but the next step.. I will enter a couple of attributes for `Animal`

```
public class Animal{
   private String name;
   private int age;
}
```

Now if i were in intellij, i would once again by an easy command be able to create a default constructor and getters and setters for every attribute.

When im in emacs i have to do that myself, and it is probably the most boring and biggest time wasting thing to do.

Also other things like being able to by fast commands get an empty template for interfaces, xmldocs, you name it.

So how could i with a couple of keystrokes get the same effect in emacs?

Comment: The general answer to these and more is sure, we could. It's rather pointless on here though. Consider asking for existing options or approaches to implement such a thing instead.

Comment: Post have been edited for clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs packages usually don't directly implement what you suggest because that requires a deep understanding of the language semantics which they typically don't have. A common approach is to get an Emacs package communicate with an external tool that provides such level of knowledge.

This approach is very trendy these days, especially thanks to the Language Server Protocool (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol).

For Java, you have

- https://melpa.org/#/eclim
- https://melpa.org/#/lsp-java